# Should I create the update function for every attribute, or should I allow partial updates?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, model-view-controller, crud

How should the updating process be implemented? Is it advisable to have an obligatory update for all attributes (First Example), or should I add null check conditionals to allow partial updates (Second Example)?

**First Example**

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public TeamDTO updateTeamById(Long id, TeamDTO teamDTO) throws ApiException {
        Optional<Team> teamOptional = teamRepository.findById(id);

        if (teamOptional.isPresent()) {
            Team existingTeam = teamOptional.get();

            // If objects ID are sent in JSON, set attributes via ID.
            if (teamDTO != null) {

                if(teamDTO.getCity() != null){
                    if (teamDTO.getCity().getId() != null) {
                        CityDTO cityDTO = cityServiceImp.getCityById(teamDTO.getCity().getId());
                        existingTeam.setCity(cityMapper.cityDTOToCity(cityDTO));
                    } else if(teamDTO.getCity().getName() != null){
                        existingTeam.setCity(cityMapper.cityDTOToCity(cityServiceImp.createCity(teamDTO.getCity())));
                    }
                }
                if(teamDTO.getStadium() != null){
                    if (teamDTO.getStadium().getId() != null) {
                        StadiumDTO stadiumDTO = stadiumServiceImp.getStadiumById(teamDTO.getStadium().getId());
                        existingTeam.setStadium(stadiumMapper.stadiumDTOToStadium(stadiumDTO));
                    } else if(teamDTO.getStadium().getName() != null){
                        existingTeam.setStadium(stadiumMapper.stadiumDTOToStadium(stadiumServiceImp.createStadium(teamDTO.getStadium())));
                    }
                }
                if(teamDTO.getDivision() != null){
                    if (teamDTO.getDivision().getId() != null) {
                        DivisionDTO divisionDTO = divisionServiceImp.getDivisionById(teamDTO.getDivision().getId());
                        existingTeam.setDivision(divisionMapper.divisionDTOToDivision(divisionDTO));
                    } else if(teamDTO.getDivision().getName() != null){
                        existingTeam.setDivision(divisionMapper.divisionDTOToDivision(divisionServiceImp.createDivision(teamDTO.getDivision())));
                    }

                }

                return teamMapper.teamToTeamDTO(teamRepository.save(existingTeam));
            }
        }
        throw new TeamNotFoundException(id);
    }
```

**Second Example**

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public TeamDTO updateTeamById(Long id, TeamDTO teamDTO) throws ApiException {
        Team team = teamMapper.teamDTOToTeam(teamDTO);
        Optional<Team> teamOptional = teamRepository.findById(id);

        if (teamOptional.isPresent()) {
            Team existingTeam = teamOptional.get();
            
            existingTeam.setName(team.getName());
            existingTeam.setDivision(team.getDivision());
            existingTeam.setCity(team.getCity());
            existingTeam.setStadium(team.getStadium());
            existingTeam.setHomeMatches(team.getHomeMatches());
            existingTeam.setAwayMatches(team.getAwayMatches());
            
            return teamMapper.teamToTeamDTO(teamRepository.save(existingTeam));
            }
        throw new TeamNotFoundException(id);
    }
```

It's a CRUD personal project. I have the same doubt with POST methods.

Answer (score 0):

With properly defined classes and there relationship, you can simply go with the **Second Approach**, which is clean and easy to understand.

With proper relationship defining, I meant the **mapping between the classes**(whether they are One-to-One or One-to-Many etc) and **their [CascadingType](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee%2F7%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html)**. In your case, you can go with **CascadeType.ALL**, which will propagate all db operations done on the parent class to child class. So when you save your parent object, your child object will also get saved. Even if your child class is not present in db, it'll create one for you.

Now, your first approach is valid for few cases too. For example, let say you are sending a request with some city data, where for the given id, the provided name is different than what it's there in the db. So, for your approach, you will not update the different name in the db, instead you will fetch the actual data from db and will be setting it. But if you follow the second approch, it'll override your existing data for the city name.

To overcome that thing from your Second Approach, you can change the cascading to **CascadeType.PERSIST**, which will just propagate the save operation to child class, not the update or delete operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate requests of complete updates with PUT requests and create multiple methods that cover partial updates using a PATCH request.

Another advantage of PATCH request is that you do not need to send TeamDTO but only the field that you need to work with.

At least in my opinion it will look much cleaner and will not have that many if checks, and it will be much easier to cover with tests as well, where you can have one test for each method, instead of having multiple tests for each if condition of the updateTeamById method to be covered.

As for how should an update be implemented, should it be an update of all fields or only partial, that depends only on your requirement.

https://www.baeldung.com/http-put-patch-difference-spring